# std::shared_ptr becomes invalid when passing as an argument by value

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Dear people of stackoverflow.

I have a class, named FcgiManager, that is intended to handle a proper ammount of fastcgi workers.
Currently it has a simple method to add a new worker to list:

```
bool FcgiManager::AddWorker() {

  workers_.push_back(std::make_unique<FcgiWorker>(server_));
  return true;
}
```

The "workers_" field is:

```
private:
 // cut 
 std::list<std::unique_ptr<FcgiWorker>> workers_;
```

The program exits with "bad weak pointer" exception.
When I trace it i see that from this method it does reache FcgiWorkes constructor, here it is:

```
FcgiWorker::FcgiWorker(std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server) :
  running_{false}, pool_{std::make_unique<FcgiRequestPool>()}, server_{server}  {
  // actual code is not important, because execution doesn't get here.
}
```

And i see, that the "server" argument shared_ptr has some martian values in it's structure, like count = 1443278, weak = -1.

But in the AddWorker() method, just before entering FcgiWorker constructor the "server_" field has appropriate values.
I have even added an "IsAlive()" method to server and tried calling server_->IsAlive() from AddWorker() and yes, it's alive.

I also tried to plainly create a worker like this:
Any advice appreciated.
    bool FcgiManager::AddWorker() {

```
  FcgiWorker test(server_);
  return true;
}
```

To check if I am doing something wrong with make_unique, but the result was the same.

Any advice appreciated.

**Update-1:**

FcgiWorker::server_ is:

```
std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server_;
```

it is initialized in the FcgiWorker constructor's initialization list, see constructor code above.

**Update-2**

FcgiManager::server_ is:

```
std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server_;
```

Here is how it is created in main.cpp:

```
auto server = std::make_shared<Dolly>();
server->BindFcgiManagerToServer();
server->Run();
```

server.cpp:

```
Dolly::Dolly() : start_time_{std::time(nullptr)} {
  fcgi_manager_ = std::make_unique<FcgiManager>();
}

void Dolly::BindFcgiManagerToServer() {
  fcgi_manager_->set_server(self());
}
```

server.h:

```
class Dolly : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Dolly> {
 private:
  // cut
  inline std::shared_ptr<Dolly> self() { return shared_from_this(); }
```

**Update-3** & **Update-4** & **5**

Created MCVE, and, oh well - it compiles and does not throw. So i guess i'll have to solve my problem myself now :)
Thanks everyone!

(MCVE updated **twice**, since it was not complete the first time)

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Dolly;

class FcgiRequestPool {
};

class FcgiWorker {

 public:
  FcgiWorker(std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server) :
    pool_{std::make_unique<FcgiRequestPool>()}, server_{server}  {
      std::cout << "worker created" << std::endl << std::flush;
  }


 private:
  std::shared_ptr<FcgiRequestPool> pool_;
  std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server_;

};

class FcgiManager {

 public:
  inline void set_server(std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server) { server_ = server; }
  bool InitWorkers() {
    auto workers_num = 4;
    auto created_workers_num = 0;
    try {
      for (created_workers_num = 0; created_workers_num < workers_num; created_workers_num++) {
        AddWorker();
      }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
      std::cout << e.what() << std::endl << std::flush;
    }

    return true;
  }
  void Run() {
    InitWorkers();
  }


 private:
  bool AddWorker() {

    workers_.push_back(std::make_unique<FcgiWorker>(server_));
    return true;
  }

  std::list<std::unique_ptr<FcgiWorker>> workers_;
  std::shared_ptr<Dolly> server_;
};

class Dolly : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Dolly> {

 public:
  Dolly() {
    fcgi_manager_ = std::make_unique<FcgiManager>();
  }
  void BindFcgiManagerToServer() {
    fcgi_manager_->set_server(self());
  }
  void Run() {
    fcgi_manager_->Run();
  }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<FcgiManager> fcgi_manager_;
  std::shared_ptr<Dolly> self() { 
    return shared_from_this(); 
  }
};


int main() {
  auto server = std::make_shared<Dolly>();
  server->BindFcgiManagerToServer();
  server->Run();

  return 0;
}
```

**Resolved**

After creating MCVE and comparing it step-by-step with the actual program, I found out, that the shared_ptr exception was generated here:

```
 pool_{std::make_unique<FcgiRequestPool>()}
```

And has no relation to the whole classes creation logic.
I am marking the answer with MCVE advice as valid, because it is actually a great advice and it did help me.

**The root cause: I was creating a unique_ptr to a class, which was derived from std::enable_shared_from_this.**

Comment: What is `FcgiWorker::server_`? When and how is it declared? And what is `FcgiManager::server_`? When and how is it declared and initialized?

Comment: Lastly, does `FcgiWorker(server_) test;` really compile? Don't you mean `FcgiWorker test(server_);`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: thank you! updated the post with FcgiWorker::server_ explanation. didn't get it, where do i create unique_ptrs to same object?
yes, FcgiWorker(server_) test; was a typo here, updated the post. it does compile the way it is in the post now. will updated reqarding FcgiManager::server_ in a minute.

Comment: Do you want shared or unique pointers?

Comment: I need shared_ptr to the server object, since lots of stuff among the program will use it, but i don't see any reason to have shared_ptr for the FcgiWorker, because only FcgiManager should hold their ownership and rule the workers.

Comment: MCVE is a good thing, will do it. Thank you.